# Thai elections and voters of 'unsound mind or of mental infirmity'

Tags: election, constitution, thailand, disenfranchisement

According to [Wikipedia's page on elections in Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_Thailand), under the [2007 constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007_constitution_of_Thailand) (not the [current one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Thailand#2017_Constitution)) certain people are ineligible to vote (emphasis is mine):

> Those barred from voting in House elections are: members of the sangha or clergy, those suspended from the privilege (for various reasons),[which?] detainees under legal or court orders, and **people of unsound mind or of mental infirmity**.[clarification needed]

Does this restriction barring *people of unsound mind or of mental infirmity* from voting still apply under the current (2017) constitution? Does the constitution (the 2007 one, or the current one) prescribe who determines when a person is deemed *of unsound mind or of mental infirmity*?

Comment: in Thailand it only matters who counts the votes, [apparently](https://www.trtworld.com/asia/thailand-vote-count-flawed-international-observers-25259), so your question is rather moot. https://www.dw.com/cda/en/thailand-still-waiting-for-a-government-as-tensions-rise/a-48130917

Comment: @Fizz I don't think those issues are relevant to this question. I really get your point, but those things happen after voting, the subject in my question happens (I think?) before that.